# "Liquify" Surface of Points Mesh in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, effects

I loaded a Mesh from a JSON File, here is my current result:

[my Project](https://www.pocketweb.de/downloads/TemporaryItems/MindHack3d/index-0.html?shape=virus)

It is an object I exported from blender as JSON and then used its vertices to create a geometry of Points (THREE.Points) (which is important for the looks of it)

I am now looking for a way to "animate" the Points, so that the "surface" looks vivid / living. So basically it should be moving around a bit, something like this (without the rotation):

[Link to animated Gif](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4a5rt2fc3otex52/Virus.gif?dl=0)

I have ruled out displacementMap, as this does not work for the PointsMaterial (or does someone know a workaround?)

Does anyone have hints or ideas? I thought of maybe morphing 2-3 Objects .. but I am not sure if this will work for a points mesh.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to achieve your desired effect is to use morph target animation (also called vertex morphing). As you can see at the following example, `three.js` does support morph target animations with points.

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets_sphere.html

There is a lot of existing literature about vertex morphing, so it should be no problem to get familiar with this technique. I suggest you create your animations in Blender, export the model to `glTF` and the load the file via `GLTFLoader` into your app like shown in the example.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I tried this, and it works, see the result here:https://www.pocketweb.de/downloads/TemporaryItems/MindHack3d/index-morph.html

Comment: Nice!! BTW: Please upvote/accept the answer if it was useful to you.